# How to find real and imaginary part of $i^{-n}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, real-numbers, integers

How do I find real and imaginary part of

$$
i^{-n}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Attempt:

Inserting n = 1, 2, 3, 4 ...

Trying to find a pattern.

n = 1
$$
1/i^1 = i^{-1} = -i
$$

n = 2

$$
 1/i^{2} = -1
$$

n = 3

$$
1/i^{3} = i
$$

n = 4

$$
1/i^{4} = 1
$$

I see some sort of a trig function pattern but I don't have any idea on how to put it.

Comment: Please show your own work/attempts before asking a question on here.

Comment: Please do respond to the comments and hints and show us your ideas.  Then the question may be re-opened.  I hope the over-eager deleters will wait a while so you have a chance to do that.

Comment: I hope the under-eager asker would have taken the initiative to improve his/her question, and attempting to answer it, or identify what motivates the question?, or, .... @GEdgar.

Comment: I think 40 minutes is much too short a time to wait.  I would delete only after a week, personally.  Even longer with reputation 1 askers.

Comment: Thank you for your unbelievable patience ....

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\displaystyle i^{-n} = \frac{1}{i^n} = \left(\frac{1}{i}\right)^n, \quad \frac{1}{i} = -i$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$i = e^{i(\pi/2 + 2k\pi)},$$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: I don't quite understand what k is

Comment: $k$ is an integer.

Comment: Not a good way for a beginner to solve this problem.